# Mutual SSL with root and intermediate CA certs

Tags: tomcat, authentication, ssl

I am trying to make a Mutual SSL call between a client and a server.  But I want the call to fail if the server does not have the client cert.

Here is more detail.

I have an intermediate cert chained to my root cert. These two are company supplied and everyone in the company have access to them.  I chain all my new certs that I create to company intermediate cert.  Any developer can do the same.

I am running a service in Tomcat and I have created a cert for my Tomcat Server chained to the intermediate cert.  On the server side my chain looks like

root <- intermediate <- server

I also have a Java client and created a client cert for it, chaining it to my intermediate cert.  On the client side my chain looks like

root <- intermediate <- client

In order to show explicitly what can be controlled with certificates I decided to split the stores.  I created a keystore and a truststore for the server, and I created a keystore and a truststore for the client.

In the server keystore I put my root, intermediate and the server keypair.
In the client keystore I put my root, intermediate and the client keypair.

In the server truststore, I put my root, intermediate and the client's public key.
In the client truststore, I put root, intermediate and the server's public key.

And everything works as expected.

Now I go into the server's truststore and remove the client's public key.  Restart my server.  When the client calls, I want the server to complain and close the connection.  However, the server seems to be fine with this situation.  Even if the server does not have the client public key, it has the certs that the client was chained to.  So everything continues to work fine.  Even if I remove the intermediate cert from the server's truststore the Mutual SSL continues to work fine.

This is not what I want.  I do not want anyone who has a cert chained to company issued intermediate to be able to call my server.  I want to be able to control the access by explicitly adding client's public key to my server's truststore.

But how, I could not figure out.  Any ideas?